# Error: undefined reference to function declaration with const std::string& and const std::vector<int>& parameters in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stl, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I'm getting an error while attempting to compile a C++ project on Code::Blocks 17.12 (Windows 10, default MinGW GCC compiler). The function

```
std::vector<int> crib_drag(const std::string&, const std::vector<int>&);
```

is declared in crib_drag.h, which I created through the C::B dialog (crib_drag.h #includes vector and string). The function  is defined in crib_drag.cpp, also created through C::B dialog:

```
#include "crib_drag.h"
std::vector<int> crib_drag(const std::string& term, const std::vector<int>& xored)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    //Do some stuff
    return ret;
}
```

main.cpp includes crib_drag.h with
    #include "crib_drag.h"
In main, crib_drag is called.
Compiling gives an undefined reference error to the crib_drag function. My understanding is that I do not need to alter the linker settings, as all files were created using default settings within the C::B project, and I have not changed the file paths of any files.

Can anyone explain what is going wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

The build log reads as follows:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in CribDrag (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\CribDrag.exe obj\Debug\crib_drag.o obj\Debug\main.o   
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
C:/[Long file path omitted]/CribDrag/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `crib_drag(std::string const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "crib_drag.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> xored1{14, 6, 31, 30, [omitted for brevity]};
    string word("overnight");
    vector<int> found_at = crib_drag(word, xored1);//Problem line
    //.....
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this function in main?

Comment: int main(){ 
vector<int> xored1{14, 6, 31, 30, 28, 12, 20, 3, 30, 8, 8, 7, 31, 23, 18, 18, 1, 4, 23, 31, 28, 8, 0, 0, [more ints omitted for brevity]};
    string word("overnight");
    vector<int> found_at = crib_drag(word, xored1);
/*More stuff*/
return 0;
}

Comment: Sorry for lack of line breaks in comment

Comment: may be update the question instead?

Comment: Updated. Thanks, didn't know I could do that (I'm new to Stack Overflow)

Comment: Check all your files are saved, it seems the `crib_drag.cpp` is not recognized as containing this function. Or maybe there is a problem in code you didn't show

Comment: try using nm and c++filt on the crib_drag.o file, like so: "nm crib_drag.o |  c++filt" (use appopriate mingw32 equivalents of nm and c++filt) and see if the symbol is containes in crib_drag.o.